# HybridAuth Facebook - 'Update user status failed!'

Tags: php, facebook, hybridauth

I have integrated latest version of HybridAuth in my website, I have created Facebook app as well, but when I use the function

```
$facebook->setUserStatus("Test");
```

it return for me error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Update user status failed! Facebook returned an error: OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action' in /home2/codinghe/public_html/inc/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php:204
```

I think by default, Facebook config allow already publish and write stream in HybridAuth. The issue can be in my facebook app ? here is how it looks:

http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/743/9943073222.jpg

Do you have any idea please? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@user3308323, did you initialize the Hybrid_Auth class and authenticate the user, before calling the setUserStatus() method? See an implementation example below as presented on the official page(http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Profile_Data_User_Status.html).

Hope this answers your question.

```
// init hybridauth
$hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

// try to authenticate with facebook
$adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "facebook" );

// update the user status
$adapter->setUserStatus(
array(
"message" => "", // status or message content
"link" => "", // webpage link
"picture" => "", // a picture link
)
);
```